# Plotting NDVI vs ASPECT in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, aspect

I tried to plot the values of NDVI against the ASPECT. but I'm getting the following error.

Error:

```
1. Array (Error) Reducer.toList, argument 'tupleSize': Invalid type.
    Expected type: Integer. Actual type: Image<[elevation]>.

 2. Invalid argument specified for ee.List(): aspect
```

Code:

```
// Importing the Shape File of Area:

var Dehradun = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-omkarthesis2022/assets/India_Dist')
                .filter('NAME_2 == "Dehradun"');

// print('Dehradun', Dehradun)
Map.addLayer(Dehradun,{},'Dehradun')
Map.centerObject(Dehradun, 8)        
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                                        // CloudMask
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function mask2Clouds(image){
   var QA = image.select('QA60')
   
  // Bits 10 and 11 cloud and cirrus 
  var cloudBitMask = (1 << 10);
  var cirrusBitMask = (1 << 11);
  
  // setting both to zero indictes clear condition
  var mask = QA.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
              .and(QA.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
              .copyProperties(image)
              .set('system:time_start',
              image.get('system:time_start'));
}

// Importing the Image Collection:
var start_date= '2019-03-01'
var end_date= '2019-06-30'

var Sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
            .sort('CLOUDY_COVER', false)
            // .filterMetadata('CLOUD_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',20)
              // Filter to study period
              .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
              // Filter to plot boundaries
              .filterBounds(Dehradun)
              .map(mask2Clouds)
              // .median()

print('Sen_2019',Sen2)
Map.addLayer(Sen2,{},'Sen2',false)

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                    // Computation NDVI
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Function to compute NDVI and add as a new band in the Image Collection:

var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
                           .copyProperties(image).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start')))
}

// Add NDVI band to image collection
var NDVI_Sen2 = Sen2.map(addNDVI);
print('NDVI_Sen2',NDVI_Sen2)

var NDVI_Sen = NDVI_Sen2.mean()
print('NDVI_Sen',NDVI_Sen)

Map.addLayer(NDVI_Sen.clip(Dehradun),{}, 'NDVI_Sen',false)

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                                        // Export Data
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: NDVI_Sen.select('nd'), 
  description:'NDVI_2019', 
  folder: 'Case_Study2022', 
  region: Dehradun, 
  scale: 20, 
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
  })
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                          // Calculating C- Factor without Smoothening
                           // C- Factor= exp[-a (NDVI)/(b-NDVI)]
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* here a and b are fitting parameter with values 1 and 2 */

var C_factor= NDVI_Sen2.map (function (image) {
  var num= image.select('nd').multiply(-2)
  var den= ee.Image.constant(1).subtract(image.select('nd'))
  var divi= num.divide(den).rename('cmap');
  var cmap= divi.pow(ee.Number(2.895))
  
  return image.addBands(cmap)

})

var C_fact = C_factor.mean()
print('C_fact',C_fact)


var imageVisParam= {'opacity':1,
                    'bands':['cmap'],
                    'min':0.0,
                    'max':1.0,
                    'palette':['#fbff16','#f19407','#ff3204','#FF0000']};


Map.addLayer(C_factor.select('cmap'),imageVisParam, 'C-factor',false)

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            // Calculate Aspect of NDVI Image
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Importing the ALOS-PALSAR DSM

var START ='2016-01-01',
    END = '2022-07-21'

var SRTM = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4")
                 .clip(Dehradun)

print('SRTM',SRTM)
Map.addLayer(SRTM,{min:0, max: 9000},'SRTM',false)

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                                          //Calculation of Aspect
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(SRTM)

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(SRTM)

Map.addLayer(aspect,{},'aspect',false)
Map.addLayer(slope,{},'slope',false)

var merge = NDVI_Sen.addBands(aspect).clip(Dehradun);
Map.addLayer(merge,{},'merge',false)
print('merge',merge)

var array = merge.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: Dehradun, scale: 1000})
                 .toArray(merge.bandNames());
                 
print('array',array)
var x = ee.List(array.get('aspect'));
var y = ee.List(array.get('nd'));


// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({array: y, axis: 0, xLabels: x}).setOptions({
  title: 'Relationship between the NDVI and Aspect',
  colors: ['cf513e'],
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Aspect (degree)',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI values',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  pointSize: 4,
  dataOpacity: 0.4,
  legend: {position: 'none'},
});
print(chart);
```

Code Link:

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/84801030c9dc6d1bfd6755ae0498336c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to 'aspect' and 'nd arrays don't have the same length. The first one has 2790 elements and the second one 2944. For running successfully the code, I arbitrarily made x and y variables equals in the number of elements (2790) but, you should fix it in the way you consider more convenient.

The main modifications are expressed in following code snippet. I also consider an arbitrary area in **Dehradun** because your asset was not available for me.

```
var array = merge.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: Dehradun, scale: 1000});
                 //.toArray(merge.bandNames());
                 
var x = ee.List(array.get('aspect'));
var y = ee.List(array.get('nd')).slice(0, 2790);;

print(x);
print(y);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({array: y, axis: 0, xLabels: x}).setOptions({
  title: 'Relationship between the NDVI and Aspect',
  colors: ['cf513e'],
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Aspect (degree)',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI values',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
  pointSize: 4,
  dataOpacity: 0.4,
  legend: {position: 'none'},
});

print(chart);
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/b3c81e4321f51db39d8a3754392a64fa) and after running it, I got printed the chart as follows.

[image]